# Why is '\0' equivalent to 0 when using pointers?

Tags: c

I'm learning C from the K&R book and on chapter 5 it shows an implementation of strcpy() with pointers involved (instead of using array indices). It says that:

```
while ((*s++ = *t++) != '\0')
```

and

```
while (*s++ = *t++)
```

Both do the same thing, and that the `!= '\0'` part is not necessary. But I don't completely understand why. Is `'\0'` equivalent to zero when a pointer pointing to that null character is dereferenced or something?

****EDIT: So if `'\0'` is equal to zero, then would this also work? ****

```
while (s[i] = t[i]) i++;
```

Comment: `'\0'` is simply equivalent to `0`, whether using pointers or no. E.g. `'\0' == 0`. Read the chapter on integer promotions.

Comment: @AntonTykhyy, there is no integer promotion taking place.  Both `'\0'` and `0` are `int`s.  Well, in C, anyway.

Comment: Why is this question tagged C++ if you're asking about C?

Comment: @CarlNorum Ya know, because "everything that works in C works in C++ too". But yeah it does, it really does! I just tried it, believe me!!!!!!!!

Comment: [check: code](http://codepad.org/Q9VV1jpR) but don't use it.

Comment: Note: the K&R version of strcpy() is 'while (*dst++ = *src++);` : no need to check against '\0', since it is implicit.

Comment: @CarlNorum ah yes, C not C++. In C character literals are `int`, in C++ `char`, otherwise overloading would become funny. Still, even in C the type of `*s++ = *t++` is `char`, so it *is* promoted — whether as `while`'s condition expression or to compare it with `'\0'`!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Both do the same thing, and that the `!= '\0'` part is not necessary. But I don't completely understand why.

Because in C, in places where a conditional expression is expected, non-0 numbers (integers and floating-point values) and non-`NULL` pointers are interpreted as true, and zero an `NULL` are considered false. But that doesn't quite have anything to do with the second part of your question.

> Is '\0' equivalent to zero when a pointer pointing to that null character is dereferenced or something?

It is **always** equivalent to `0`, in any context. Even if you do `void *foo = '\0';`, it will set `foo` to `NULL`, since an integer literal zero is a suitable initializer for a pointer and it is converted to `NULL`. But I don't see why you are asking about pointers, since you are just comparing integrals with integrals (`char` and `int` are both integral types).

Comment: Again, why are you downvoting thia?

Comment: Yes, I know you had hinted at it, I just thought it's relevant enough to have been stated explicitly (and for the record, I up- not downvoted).

Comment: @bitmask I know you didn't downvote, thanks -- the question is directed towards whomever did.

Comment: @H2CO3 Just come after getting serial down-votes, You also got unexplained downvoted on an accepted answer -Not good, its Site Vandalism. Do updated your answer may be someone wanted to undo his down-votes.

Comment: @grijeshChauhan Oh, you got those too? Not nice... :(

Comment: @H2CO3 yep :( it is first time with me '(.. once I find some clue I will kill him...

Answer (score 2):

Yes, `'\0'` nul char is `0`.

To understand conditional expressions consider my following   points:

**One:** Because associativity assignment operator `=` is right-to-left hence expression

```
a = b = c;
```

is equivalents to:

```
a = (b = c);
```

in effects equivalents to :

```
b = c;
a = b;
```

**Two:** the pointer assignment expression:

```
*s++ = *t++;
```

is equivalents to:

```
*s = *t; 
t++;
s++;
```

**Three:** and an expression:

```
con = *s++ = *t++;
```

is equivalents to:

```
*s = *t; 
con = *s;
t++;
s++;
```

**Four:**

```
(*s++ = *t++) != '\0'
```

is equivalents to:

```
*s = *t; 
*s != '\0';
t++;
s++;
```

**[Answer]**:
So in second while loop:

```
while (*s++ = *t++);
//       ^      ^
//       |      |
//     assign then increments 
//   then break condition = *s  (updated value at *s that is \0 at the end)
```

Instruction `"*s++ = *t++` copies value at address by `t` to value at address by `s` and then that value becomes break condition in while loop, So loop runs till `\0` found which is equal to `0`.

So conditional  expression `(*s++ = *t++)` is equivalent to  `(*s++ = *t++) != '\0'`  both runs till `*s != 0`.

The last while:

```
while (s[i] = t[i])  i++; 
//       ^      ^     ^
//       |      |     increments 
//   assign then increments 
//   then break condition = s[i]  (s[i] is \0 at the end)
```

Instruction `s[i] = t[i]`  first copies value of `t[i]` to `s[i]` then value of `s[i]` uses as breaking condition of while-loop that is `\0` (=0) at end.

Comment: There is no ASCII involved.  `\0` is just `0`.

Comment: @CarlNorum you means `\0` is not a char ?

Comment: Sure it's a character constant, but that doesn't have anything to do with ASCII.

Comment: @CarlNorum you means in any C implementation that might use other then ASCII `\0` is still `0` according to C standards?

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted the character that is typed as 0, as in ascii 48, you would naturally use '0'.

Since that '0' is already taken, to specify the "special" NUL character, a different sequence is needed.  As many people understand that NUL equals the binary value of 0, they opted for '\0'.

So

```
'\0' == 0
```

returns true, but

```
'0' == 48  // ASCII only, EBCDIC programmers need to lookup their own values ;)
```

returns true too

And yes, there are many ways one could write the `strcpy()` internals.  However, pointers and arrays are only representationally equivalent, and sometimes (even if it is not necessary) an explicit comparator can prevent people from focusing on the wrong elements of a demonstrative example.

So, I believe that instead of forcing the reader to understand that the loop would terminate when stumbling upon a NUL character, they just wrote in a clause (which any decent compiler would probably optmize away) that made the termination apparent.  After all, they really were focusing on the copying aspect, not the "boolean" to `int` mapping.

Comment: `'\0'` is not a special escape sequence.  It's a literal octal character constant with value `0`.

Comment: "`'0' == 60` returns true too" -- not on my EBCDIC mainframe.

Comment: @H2CO3 Touche, and all too true.  Still I'll wager that `'0' != ASCII_NUL`, which was the point to be made.

Comment: @EdwinBuck :) Yay. But better be entirely precise in order not to spread even more confusion among beginners.

Comment: @H2CO3 Agreed, but overabundance of precision can make bigger issues very hard to express.  Just look at the precise legal language, and realize what it looks like from an outside perspective.

Comment: @EdwinBuck But we are programmers, not lawyers. We at least don't want to **intentionally** make it hard to read :P

Comment: @H2CO3 Of course.  We reserve such activities of intentionally hard to read coding to competitions http://www.ioccc.org (and the workplace, it seems) ;)

Comment: @chux Thanks again my friend.  I only wish I had people as through during code reviews! :)

Comment: @Edwin Buck I'll have my agent talk with your agent.  We'll do lunch.  Loved your last film - no - no - wait: wrong genre! :)

Answer (score 0):

The backslash indicates that there will be some *special* case in string for example:

```
`\r` means carriage return and it is equal 13
`\n` means line feed and it is equal 10
there are more of these and in your mentioned case:
`\0` means null and is equal 0
```

That is how `c` works.

Comment: `\n` means line feed - true.  It value equals 10 when using the nearly universal ASCII character coding.  But C does not define `\n` to be 10 nor require ASCII.  Similar for `\r`.

Answer (score 0):

`'\0'` and `0` mean the same thing, so using the former is just syntactic sugar.

The point is to make the code more readable, as we're dealing here with strings of characters, so it's more consistent to use the character-symbol for the number zero, used to terminate C-strings.

If you deal with numbers, it's better style to use `0`, if you deal with characters, `'\0'` is better, and if you deal with pointers, `NULL` is best. All 3 symbols mean the same, it's just for clarity.